# How to solve problem with 5.1 speakers connecting to 3 connectors?

Tags: audio, connection

I got the sound card on the mother board and Genius 5.1 speakers.

There are 3 output connectors at the cable of speakers
There are 3 input connectors in the computer.

How should I pair the colours and settings? It seems I don't seem to be succeful at pairing them with settings, so I can hear the bass and central satelite at the same time. It's central, or bass.. never both in the correct positions.

Comment: Don't confuse `input` and `output` with `male` and `female`.  Speakers do not have output connectors, because nothing comes out of the speaker via the cable.  Speakers only have input connectors, because the signal goes into the speaker via the cable.  This connector is often a 3.5mm male stereo plug, but does not necessarily have to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remap the connectors to the speakers. Here's an [excellent tutorial](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/268).